# create a list in prolog in range of two numbers

Tags: prolog

I want to build list of numbers that are in range of two given numbers.

For example: `betweenRange(1,5,X)`

will give the answer: `X=[1,2,3,4,5]`.

any idea how to do that?

I've tried something like:

```
elementsBetween(N1, N2, [N1|_]):-
   N2 =:= N1.
elementsBetween(N1, N2, List):-
   N2 > N1, N2New is N2-1, 
   elementsBetween(N1, N2New, [N2|List]).
```

but its not working, some problem with backtracking after the recursion.

Comment: Lots of ideas. What have you tried?

Comment: somthing like this: 
elementsBetween(N1,N2,[N1|_]):- N2=:=N1.
elementsBetween(N1,N2,List):- N2>N1, N2New is N2-1, elementsBetween(N1,N2New,[N2|List]).
but its not working

Comment: `numlist/3` is offered by many implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
betweenToList(X,X,[X]) :- !.
betweenToList(X,Y,[X|Xs]) :-
    X =< Y,
    Z is X+1,
    betweenToList(Z,Y,Xs).
```

Output:

```
?- betweenToList(1,5,X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

?- betweenToList(1,2,X).
X = [1, 2].

?- betweenToList(1,8,X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].

?- betweenToList(1,1,X).
X = [1].

?- betweenToList(1,0,X).
false.
```

Same logic by decreasing `Y` you can use `reverse/2` (Easy to implement):

```
betweenDecYAux(X,X,[X]) :- !.
betweenDecYAux(X,Y,[Y|Ys]) :-
    X =< Y,
    Z is Y-1,
    betweenDecYAux(X,Z,Ys).

betweenDecY(X,Y,R) :-
    betweenDecYAux(X,Y,L),
    reverse(L, R). % reverse [c,b,a] to [a,b,c]
```

Output:

```
?- betweenDecY(1,6,X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

?- betweenDecY(2,8,X).
X = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].

?- betweenDecY(1,0,X).
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```
    betweenRange(Lo, Hi, Range) :- findall(N, between(Lo, Hi, N), Range).
```

It puts all *N*s that satisfy `between(Lo,Hi,N)` into a list *Range*.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, use [numlist](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl):

```
numlist(From, To, List).
```